# how to update roll up summary field after stage change toclosed lost

Tags: workflow, formula

I am trying to update the roll up summary field(Total Amount) value with minus after stage is change to "Closed lost" in Opportunity.

My scenario is i generated the report using matrix format with stage wise that time total amount is add with "closed lost " also. Total amount is Roll-Up Summary (SUM Opportunity Product) 
i create the  work flow if the opportunity stage is equal to "closed lost" i need the update the Total amount,but i cannot see the field in drop down.

How i update the field if any other way.

Comment: Your question somehow appearing to be confusing. Please edit the question and add details on the 2nd paragraph. If possible add what you have tried so far.

Comment: Hi Santanu, I am using total amount field as a roll up summary based on performa invoice. I am generate the report group by stage wise and sum of the total amount is add all the stage. And closed lost amount is minus from the other stage

Answer (score 0):

Roll up summary fields don't answer to the same rules as other fields. They are calculated on their own ([link](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_order_of_execution.htm)).

They **canno't be updated manually as you try with a workflow field update**. Hence why they're not in the dropdown list.

If you want to customize the behavior of your Total Amount in some way, as you canno't update manually the roll up, you'll need a new field , populated by a trigger or a workflow, depending on the **Stage** as you mention

Comment: Hi Simon, because i want to show the values in stage wise in report. And i use the matrix report format,that time all stage value sum. Here i  sum of the total amount and i dont want to the total amount of the closed lost

Comment: Ok, if you want to display the total amount if the opportunity isn't closed lost, and remove the total amount if it's closed lost, you could use a number formula field  
for example, 
IF(ISPICKVAL(Stage, 'Closed Lost'), 0, Total_Amount__c)